# Centroid of Mandelbrot Set

Tags: fractals, centroid

How to find the geometric [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of [Mandelbrot Set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html)?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just like its [area](http://mrob.com/pub/muency/areaofthemandelbrotset.html), it's unlikely that the centroid of the Mandelbrot set is known exactly.

A [1996 discussion](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/mand-area.html) says that the centroid is approximately at $-0.28781$.